# How to pass data in $ .post ajax with php

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, request

Good morning people. I'm new to PHP and need help with an API implementation.

I need to pass the ajax.post the client data, email, and password. When I step directly in PHP it works perfectly. But when I send via data, it returns 500 from the server.

An example:

```
public function createUser(){
    $this->post("api/license-manager/users", [
        "email" => "xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com",
        "name" => "xxxx 232r4 xx"
    ]);
    return $this->result();
}
```

I wish it would work this way:

```
var data = {
    'email': "xxxxx@test.com",
    'name': "Xxxxxx 001323"
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/midleware/createuser/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What's in the server error log?

Comment: For now nothing, why can not I test. I was not able to create a variable or anything like that to send in ajax.

I can not get out of here. I got caught in this part

Comment: Before ajax request go to your browser's inspect and network tab. Then send the request and in response section get the actually error.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error it's come from the server. You need to see what's in the server error log.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment, however you need 50 REP. So here is a shot at an answer although the question seems too ambiguous, so I'm making assumptions here. Feel free to add more data so I can give you a hand.

When trying to look at whats happening I'm assuming that createUser() I can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish, it seems like you are mixing JS and php. When you are interacting with the database in laravel you will be inside of an action that started out as some sort of ajax request, and is sent from something in your javascript front end. I'm assuming that this is set up properly as follows from your example.

```
var data = {
    'email': "xxxxx@test.com",
    'name': "Xxxxxx 001323"
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/midleware/createuser/',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

now, you may need to do something with your headers remember you'll need to send a CSRF token somehow if your /midleware/createuser/ route is on the routes/web.php file, or you'll need to send some sort of token if your route is in the routes/api.php section.

Once you hit your route properly and defer it to a controller method for example you can handle it in the controller or defer it to a FormRequest object that has some advantages over a general request.

You might make your controller resolve your request out of the IOC container by having this function in your "UserLicenceController" You can make a request with an artisan command at the terminal

```
php artisan make:request CreateLicenseRequestForm
```

Then you can call it in your create function, I use this convention

```
public function create(CreateLicenseRequestForm $form)
{
    return $form->persist()
}
```

Then in your form, set your "$rules" array to validate whatever you need. Like the user only exists once, and has paid or whatever. Your authorize function to make sure you have authorization to actually make the request for example maybe someone is playing around with routes and is trying to grant themselves access on another account.

Then in your persist method once everything is validated and happy, return your response. If it's to a JS request you probably want JSON

something like

```
public function persist()
{
    //DO YOUR DB WORK HERE

    return response($message, $statusCode);
}
```

This may have been way more than you need or way less depending on your understanding of the steps. Feel free to follow up with more info.

Good luck.

Comment: this way it will not work, because this post is in a third party api. that I really need is to pass the email and password on a data, instead of going directly with it in the first example

Comment: Ok @rodrigo-santos this is too unclear for me. Without reading your mind you aren’t putting up any code for me to consider. All I can see is something that looks frankly a bit out of the ordinary. Also never send a password through a 3rd party API that sounds very risky. You should be using some sort of token authentication or hashed data. That being said, unless you drop a bunch of described code before and after your issue so someone can help you through the part of your problem you don’t understand, I don’t see how I or anyone else can help you any further.